# CSRF token to delete Airflow Dag in airflow UI using REST API call

Tags: etl, airflow, csrf-token, rest

The Purpose is to delete airflow dag from UI with rest api call. I tried the api call 
`.../delete?dag_id=<dag_id>`
,this rest call fails saying CSRF token is missing. How to get CSRF token from airflow server ? or is there a better way to delete dag from airflow UI in automated way ? (not manually pressing delete button from airflow UI)

Comment: Hi - did you ever find an answer/workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for airflow vesrion >= 1.10 you can use the experimental REST API

here is a code example:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def delete_dag(airflow_server_address ,dag_id):
    url = urljoin(airflow_server_address, '/api/experimental/dags/'+dag_id)
    requests.delete(url)
```

this will delete the dag runs and data from the database.
make sure you delete the dag .py file first, otherwise the dag will continue to appear in the airflow GUI.

Comment: this works, but i had to use airflow delete_dag cli command, since anyway i have to run cli command to delete .py file

Comment: you can use the cli commend as well. but you asked for deleting using rest api call. @HemanthKumar

Comment: Using the rest api works only if the underlying .py file is deleted else the UI will still have the entry, thats what i meant. Thank you

Comment: you right, it's written in the answer. please mark as accepted answer if you find it correct.

Comment: stack overflow says i don't have enough reputation do that action. this answer is accepted from my side. Thanks.

Comment: Hi  @Oded Rozencweig , i'm getting a 404 error for the Delete Rest API that you have suggested. Im using 1.10.9 version. Im able to run other Rest API but not this one. Am i missing something ?